# JAVA:method and using one class

Tags: java

I want to use different methods in a class. But I know that only the `main` method will be read by the compiler. So how can I use other methods, objects and data in the `main` method? Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: You should look for a java tutorial first.

Comment: Unless you catch up with basic java first, I am afraid you won't be able to understand the below answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java compiler `javac` will compile all methods. JVM will *start* executing program from `main()` method that can call other methods either from current class or other classes. For more information take a java tutorial (for example referenced by Sergeii or any other one).

Have a pleasant time learning Java!

Answer (score 2):

Try to read  [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) from Oracle (Sun)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A{

  public void print(){ System.out.println("Printing"); }

  public static void printStatic(){ System.out.println("static Printing"); }

  public static void main(String args[]){  

    printStatic();
    A.printStatic();

    new A().print();
  }
}
```

Above code has what you need but
I suggest you to learn basic java.

Answer (score 0):

`Entry point of a program in Java is its Main`, and every program must have one and only one main program (In Java Web App, there is no main method).

Try reading `Head First Java by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates`... awesome and fun to learn.